# Displaying pictures from a file path on a Image control

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a folder which contains images to be used on records on a form.
How do I get **a single image** to display on an unbound image control for all records with the same `ItemName` and `Model`?

I expect Items with the same `ItemName` and `Model` to use the same image. The images are currently named using a unique id corresponding to the `ItemName` field. e.g Image corresponding to `ItemName: Microwave` `Model: Q12V` `ItemNumber: 1223`, is named `1223.jpg`. I have searched and searched for any ways around this but I haven't come across anything.

My supervisor has said that altering the table by creating a new field is not an option.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

```
 Function GetImagePath(strIN As String) As String
 Dim strP As String
 strP = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonatedItems").Connect
 strP = Mid(Left(strP, InStrRev(strP, "\")), InStrRev(strP, "=") + 1) + "ItemImages\"
        GetImagePath = strP & _
        IIf(Dir(strP & strIN & ".jpg") <> "", strIN & ".jpg", "default-picture.bmp")
```

On the image  `ControlSource` property:

```
=GetImagePath([ItemName] & "_" & Replace([Model],"/","_"))
```

Comment: I have never used Picture property of Image control. I would just use an expression in its ControlSource property.

Comment: @June7 Would writing an expression in the control source require some kind of digging out the image path? The control is currently unbound and I was thinking that rewriting the last loop as in the last part of my post would do the trick. I am not sure on how to go about any of this.

Comment: I am not understanding how images are saved. Are they not all in a known folder location? Expression in ControlSource can include a function that builds path and concatenates with field, such as: `=ImagePath() & Nz([fieldname], "default-picture.bmp")`.

Comment: @June7 The image path exists with the backend file. I'm currently digging it out using `strBackEndPath = Mid(Left(strBackEndPath, InStrRev(strBackEndPath, "\")), i) + "ItemImages\" `.

Comment: There will always be an ImageNumber value but possibly not a matching image file in which case default-picture.bmp must be displayed and that image is in same folder location as other images?

Comment: @June7 Yes! using a single image for all those records which has the same `ItemName` and `Model` values is his main emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since neither ItemName nor Model is part of image name, really don't see how they are relevant. Certainly can't be a factor in selecting image.

Consider something like:

```
Function GetImagePath(strIN As String) As String
Dim strP As String
strP = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonatedItems").Connect
strP = Mid(Left(strP, InStrRev(strP, "\")), InStrRev(strP, "=") + 1)
If Dir(strP & strIN & ".jpg") <> "" Then
    GetImagePath = strP & strIN & ".jpg"
ElseIf  Dir(strP & strIN & ".png") <> "" Then
    GetImagePath = strP & strIN & ".png"
Else
    GetImagePath = strP & "default-picture.bmp"
End If
End Function
```

Call the function from ControlSource of Image control:
`=GetImagePath([ItemNumber])`

If images must be differentiated by ItemName and/or Model then need to rename images and concatenate fields in function call:
`=GetImagePath([ItemName] & "_" & Replace([Model], "/", "_")`

Comment: Wao you just blew my mind here. I have tried this out and I can see some positive signs. In some cases I get `No current record` alert. It would be good if I can rename the images so that it can be differentiated using `ItemName` and `Model` fields. The problem is, there are difficult characters on the Model fields e.g `V5/20S.EE`. And also, some images have `.PNG` extensions.

Comment: Will have to expand code to check for various file extensions. Give image names using Model more like: `V5_20S.EE` then function can do Replace() operation on data for the / character. Coding to manage all possible invalid characters could get a bit complicated.

Comment: Do you mean renaming the images using itemName and Model e.g `ItemName: `Microwave` and `Model: V5/20S.EE` to `Microwave_V5_20S.EE` then using the new name in the function would complicate things?

Comment: Maybe not too badly if / is only invalid character. Would have to concatenate fields and replace / with underscore to match actual image file names. This could be done in function call: `=GetImagePath([ItemName] & "_" & Replace([Model], "/", "_"))`.

Comment: I implemented the code and but i keep getting `No current record` alert for some records. The default-picture also doesn't load. I must have not implemented the code properly.

Comment: You will have to edit question to show attempted code. Why would you get `No current record`? There is no recordset involved in my example code and no looping.

Comment: I have resolved the no current record issue. Code edited. Please see as the default image doesn't load on the control.

Comment: See latetest edit of code in my answer. You are using an earlier version that had bad logic.

Comment: Are you using `=GetImagePath([ItemNumber])` Or `=GetImagePath([ItemName] & "_" & Replace([Model], "/", "_"))` In the controlsource?

Comment: Thank you again for your support on this. I have renamed the images using ItemName and Model. For all `.jpg files` I am now trying to implement the code so as to handle `.PNG files` as well. Please see edit. I would very much appreciate it if you can edit the your answer a bit so I can mark as complete. This is really good!